# ngx-vis: "TypeError: Array or DataSet expected"

Tags: angular, vis.js

When running ngx-vis, I get the error "TypeError: Array or DataSet expected". I've used the following code to import it:

```
import { VisNetworkService, Data, Node, Options, Edge } from 'ngx-vis';

import {DataSet} from 'vis-data/peer';

// import { DataSet } from "vis-data/peer/esm/vis-data" // I also tried this line with the same result
```

Results in the terminal:

```
    value vis-network.min.js:58
    setData vis-network.min.js:58
    ff vis-network.min.js:58
    create ngxvis.js:282
    createNetwork ngxvis.js:1116
    ngOnInit ngxvis.js:1077
    Angular 24
    RxJS 6
    Angular 8
```

- Angular version: 13.2.3
- Typescript Version: 4.5.5

---

I have spotted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213015/core-js-error-typeerror-array-or-dataset-expected-for-vis-network-angular-10) but changing the import line does not help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the import to `import { DataSet } from 'vis-data/esnext';` ?